# Loop through multiple files in different folders in R

Tags: r

I have folders named 2021ClientA, 2021ClientB.... each folder has a summary textfile named summary.csv

I want to create a loop that locates folders starting with 2021 then extract their summary.csv file and rbind at the end to create one dataframe

Comment: Try this: ```dir(path = 'folder_name',  pattern = '2021Client.*/summary.csv', full.names = T, recursive = T) |>
    lapply(read.csv) |> do.call(what = rbind)```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the current directory to the folder containing the 2021XXX folders, you can do:

```
folders <- list.files(pattern = "^2021")
n <- length(folders)
dfs <- vector("list", length = n)
for(i in 1:n){
  dfs[[i]] <- read.csv(file.path(folders[i], "summary.csv"))
}
bigdf <- do.call(rbind, dfs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
iris %>% write.csv('~/Desktop/Stack/2021CustomerA/summary.csv')
iris %>% write.csv('~/Desktop/Stack/2021CustomerB/summary.csv')
iris %>% write.csv('~/Desktop/Stack/2021CustomerC/summary.csv')
iris %>% write.csv('~/Desktop/Stack/2022CustomerA/summary.csv')

setwd('~/Desktop/Stack/')

read_csv_files <- data.frame()

for(i in list.files()){
    if(grepl('2021',i)){
        setwd(sprintf('~/Desktop/Stack/%s',i))
    }else{
        next
    }
    
    new_df <- read.csv('summary.csv')
    
    read_csv_files <- rbind(read_csv_files,new_df)
    setwd('~/Desktop/Stack/')

}
```